# flutter retrofit ignore content-type

Tags: android, flutter, dart, retrofit

I would like to create app with https requests and i use retrofit. But when i get response in headers not contains content-type. Because of this, retrofit considers that the response is a string, but there is json. Can I ignore the lack of content-type and always parse the response as json? Unfortunately I can't change the API.

this is my code

````
abstract class Api{
  factory Api(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _Api;

  @JSONMessageCodec()
  @POST("secret =)")
  Future<List<String>> getRooms(@Header("Authorization") String basicAuth, @Header("Content-Type") String type);
}```
````